# In C++, Passing char array to super give erros?

Tags: c++, stack, arrays

I have this structure:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void doACopy(char* strToCopy) {
        strcpy(str, strToCopy);
    }
private:
    char str[4];
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void doSomething() {
        char toCopy[4];
        toCopy[0] = 'a'; toCopy[1] = 'b'; toCopy[2] = 'c';
        Base::doACopy(toCopy); // is there any problem passing toCopy here?
    }
};
```

I know toCopy is allocated on stack. Is there any problem on passing this array to super, in this case Derived::doACopy?

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time using `std::string`.

Answer (score 6):

There's no problem with the stack memory being destroyed.  `toCopy` is valid until `doSomething` returns, and by that time the strcpy is complete.

But they must both be length 4, and you must NUL-terminate `toCopy`:

```
private:
    char str[4];

// ...
char toCopy[4];
toCopy[0] = 'a'; toCopy[1] = 'b'; toCopy[2] = 'c';
toCopy[3] = '\0';
```

As is, there's no NUL-terminator (or even room), and this will cause a buffer overflow during `strcpy`.

Comment: so the problem I'm having is not becasue of the stack stuff is because of this NULL-terminator.

Comment: Probably, strcpy will copy characters up to and including the first NULL it finds. If you don't provide the terminator it will keep going until it finds one in memory. Google `buffer overflow`, or `buffer overrun`.

Answer (score 2):

**char** toCopy[4]; will be available and exist until the end of method doSomething . And regarding the problem that you have ...As Naveen said ... it's because you didn't put a terminator char "NULL"... to fix this issue you may rewrite the definition of toCopy are as following :-

```
char toCopy[4] = {0};
```

I highly recommend you to use string instead of plain array of char ... so if we rewrite the code with new changes ... it will be like this ...

```
 #include<string>
using std::string;

class Base
{
public:
    void doACopy(string & strToCopy) {
        str = strToCopy;
    }
private:
    string str;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void doSomething() {
        string toCopy = "abc";
        Base::doACopy(toCopy); // is there any problem passing toCopy here?
    }
};

is not easy !!!
```